# how to assign a variable in procedure in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana, hana-sql-script

here i tried to give discount based on quantity ordered by using procedure. but i dont know how assign a value of column to the variable in procedure.

here my code:

```
create column table "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE"
(
"SALES_ID" integer,
"PRODUCT_ID" integer,
"QTY" integer,
"DISCOUNT" integer,
"SALES_AMOUNT" Double
);

insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (1,101,15,1500);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (2,102,25,2500);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (3,103,35,3500);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (4,104,40,4000);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (5,105,27,2700);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (6,106,32,3200);
insert into "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" ("SALES_ID","PRODUCT_ID","QTY","SALES_AMOUNT") values (7,107,19,1900);

create procedure "KABIL_PRACTICE"."IF_ELSE_DISC"
language sqlscript
as begin
declare QTY integer ;
select "QTY" from "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" := QTY;
if ( QTY > 25)
then
update "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" set "DISCOUNT" = 5;
else if
update "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" set "DISCOUNT" = 1;
end if;
end if;
end;
```

anyone help me....

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case of not using SQL enough but instead trying to force an imperative programming style on a SQL database.
All you want to do is update a table based on a condition, isn't it?

In that case, there is no need for procedural logic at all (and that's true for any SQL database).

```
UPDATE "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE" 
SET "DISCOUNT" = (CASE WHEN "QTY" >25 
                     THEN 2 
                     ELSE 1 
                  END) ;
```

This will store the computed `"DISCOUNT"` value in the table with no looping, in a single command.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign variables by selecting columns into them. For example:

```
SELECT QTY INTO QTY FROM KABIL_PRACTICE.SALES_IF_ELSE
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but here i used this code: 'QTY  = select "QTY" from "KABIL_PRACTICE"."SALES_IF_ELSE";
  if ( QTY > 25)' but it shows an error like this: inconsistent datatype: INT type is not comparable with TABLE type.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why you did this? The error occurred because you are comparing a temporary table to a single integer. You need to use a variable instead of a table if you want to evaluate against an integer.

Comment: hi Dave,                                                                                                           
            i just want to check the values from the "QTY" column and if the quantity is greater than 25, I would like to give the discount .